# Resetting Countdown to Start at Beginning Again After Winding Down to End

Tags: jquery, ajax

You would think this would be a easy as falling off a log, and I am sure this will become easy for me, but for now I am hoping for a quick assist to finish this off.  I have a countdown and I have a page refreshing its content with ajax.  The restart of the countdown should be triggered by the completion of the page update... and there should be a retry handler if the update fails.  I will be happy to jsut be able to know how to restart the countdown when it gets to 0

I have a countdown from 60 seconds to 0, in increments of 5 seconds. This works:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var counter = 60;

    var seks = $('#seks').html(counter);//save copy to reduce querying
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        counter -= 5;
        seks.fadeOut('slow',function(){//use callback after animation
        seks.html(counter).fadeIn('slow');//now fade back in once out is done
    });
    if (counter == 0) {
        clearInterval(interval);

    }
}, 5000);
});</script>
```

The html is this:

```
Next update in <span id="seks"></span> seconds</h5>
```

The problem is restarting the countdown after the page updates.  I tried a few variations, I thought this might do it, adding a start call, or an attempt at one, to the script that updates the page, but it does not work:

```
setInterval(function() {
    var fadeInData = function fadeInData() { $('#updateshere').fadeIn(); }
    var loadData = function loadData() { $('#updateshere').load('http://launchpad-001.com/_firingRange/_danTestPageHits/', fadeInData); }
    $('#updateshere').fadeOut(loadData);  
    interval(); /*  added this to try resetting interval timer, but it does nto work*/
}, 60000);
```

Comment: place this var (var counter = 60;) inside your timing function, and try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are better off placing your `setInterval` into a function of its own, then calling it when the counter reaches zero. See this snippet below. For the demo I made the timer start at 10 seconds, and update every 2 seconds for demonstration purposes.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var seconds = 10;
    var atInterval = 2;
    var counter = seconds;

    var seks = $('#seks').html(counter);//save copy to reduce querying
    var interval;
    var startInterval = function(){ 
        interval = setInterval(function() {
            counter -= atInterval;
            seks.fadeOut('slow',function(){//use callback after animation
                seks.html(counter).fadeIn('slow');//now fade back in once out is done
            });
            if (counter == 0) {
                clearInterval(interval);

                // Reset the counter, and start the interval timer again
                counter = seconds;
                startInterval();
            }
        }, atInterval*1000);
    };
  
  startInterval();
  
  setInterval(function() {
    var fadeInData = function fadeInData() { $('#updateshere').fadeIn(); }
    var loadData = function loadData() { $('#updateshere').load('http://launchpad-001.com/_firingRange/_danTestPageHits/', fadeInData); }
    $('#updateshere').fadeOut(loadData);  
   
}, seconds*1000); 
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Next update in <span id="seks"></span> seconds</h5>
```

Comment: Drakes, today, so far, you my hero.  Thank you for the fix and he explanation.  This helps me a lot